# typescript crypto-js how to hash data using sha256 algorithm and key

Tags: javascript, typescript, encryption, cryptography

I am using typescript version 3.7.2 to encrypt data using crypto-js.

Algorithm - sha256

But my code is generating wrong hashed data.

The code is working fine without using any key to hash data like

```
CryptoJS.SHA256(message).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
```

But when I use key it is doing wrong hashing

Here is the full code.
Hope you can help. Thank you in advance

```
    import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

    let order_id = 'order_EFph1itQK4z1NQ',
    let payment_id = 'pay_EFph2XRs3vkaB8',

    let generated_signature = CryptoJS.SHA256(order_id + "|" + payment_id, secret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
 // secret is some key
```

value of generated signature (our end)

```
1a45e3be48f64911d372bcccd9c4dbe7dca9dab716603e4e80c2e55f701bde7a
```

The hash value to compare with(sent by payment gateway)

```
e236e8fe62c54546b85dede32c432d4c73c27157840a8ba67cfc09270b53064a
```

The hash value generated by online website https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output

```
e236e8fe62c54546b85dede32c432d4c73c27157840a8ba67cfc09270b53064a
```

i.e.Hash value generated by online website and sent by payment gateway is matching,  that means there is something wrong about our code.
Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are expecting to compute SHA256 HMAC, but you are actually computing the SHA256 hash of the message `order_id + "|" + payment_id`. The `secret` argument passed to SHA256 function is ignored.

Replace `CryptoJS.SHA256` with `CryptoJS.HmacSHA256` and your code will work as expected.

Comment: It just ignores the 2nd argument. In JS you are allowed to pass additional arguments even if the function doesn't declare them. SHA256 is an algorithm that only takes 1 argument - the message to hash.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you're using. I noticed that it doesn't provide type declarations by itself, so it's possible that @types/crypto-js is out of sync with the most recent version of the library.

Comment: The official docs don't mention the 2nd argument for any of the hashing functions: https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#hashing

Comment: OK, I thought I saw an example where indeed a second parameter for SHA256 was used, but I cannot find it anymore. Probably just confirmation bias from my side. I didn't know that JS simply ignored additional parameters (or forgot about it). Anyway, if you find such an example: use HMAC directly! There is more to HMAC than just SHA-256.

Comment: @Tomasz how do I solve the problem that you have mentioned @types/crypto-js is out of sync

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'

    private _hash(data: string) {
        return CryptoJS.SHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(data)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).